# Selenium webdriver convert CSS selector to XPath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

This is for Selenium webdriver xPath. Please refer to screen capture. I am writing following XPath for Collection #1 button, but this is just temporary text which has been given to button. but this text will be change once BLL is implemented. So how do I define XPath? In screen capture UI and HTML is there.

For now I gave following xpath in my script.

```
//*[@class='infix' and text()='Collection #1']
```

This is xPath

```
/html/body/esx-root/div/esx-prospect-landing/esx-community-search-hero/div[2]/div[2]/div/button[1]
```

**This is CSS**

```
html body esx-root div.container esx-prospect-landing.ng-star-inserted esx-community-search-hero div.content-wrapper div.bottom-wrapper div.hero-actions button span.infix
```

**This is CSS Selector**

```
.hero-actions > button:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2)
```

How do I define short way XPath in my script.

[image]

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: You need to add more details. As it is now, we don't know what it is you are trying to do. You say that the picture shows temporary text... what is the final text? How will the final text be determined? What is BLL? Spend some more time thinking about the problem and add more description in your question as to what you want to achieve.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, your current XPath works - you just want it to be more readable? I would suggest being a bit more specific, e.g. `//span[@class='infix' and text()='Collection #1']` I CSS selector is probably the better choice anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go for some tutorial to write effective and customized xpath or css path

1. There are lots of tutorials website you can refer as per your interest.

   https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

   https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/css-selector-selenium-locator-selenium-tutorial-6/

   https://selenium-by-arun.blogspot.com/2012/12/25-locate-ui-elements-by-xpath.html
2. Always prefer relative xpath instead of absolute xpath and top of it, prefer CSS selector until you don't have final choice to using xpath (locate element based on text)

Now for your case you can refer below xpath to locate the element based on text

```
//div/button[contains(.,'Collection #1')]
```

OR

```
//button/span[class='infix'][contains(.,'Collection #1')]
```

And below CSS selector

```
.hero-actions>button span.infix
```

Additionally, you can take the other surrounding elements to make it unique.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This helps